# TFSMigrator Validate command giving custom type errors

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, version-control

We are using Data Migration tool to migrate devop server 2020 to devops service. During the validation process we got the error messages mentioned below.

There is no process mentioned against each projects in our collections. I believe we can’t set any process for our existing collection if one is not already there.

I have gone through the link mentioned below but it is talking about running feature wizard which is not available in Devop Server 2020.

Which process xml file i need to update?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-processtemplates?view=azure-devops#update-to-a-system-process

[image]

**Here are the error messages;**

**Errors from the log file**

[image]

**Here are the version details;**

Data Migration Tool Version: DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2020.1RTW_18.181.17017273

Devop Server Version: 18.181.31230.2 (Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1)

Comment: Have you checked any XML process templates you may still have?

Answer (score 0):

For error `TF402574`, you can edit the `ProcessConfiguration.xml` file to add the missing named `TypeField` element.

You can review [ProcessConfiguration XML element reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) for required TypeField elements.

For the example process specifies the following TypeField elements. If any of these are missing, you'll receive error `TF402574`.

```
<TypeFields>
    <TypeField refname="System.AreaPath" type="Team" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="RemainingWork" format="format h" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority" type="Order" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" type="Effort" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity" type="Activity" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationStartInformation" type="ApplicationStartInformation" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationLaunchInstructions" type="ApplicationLaunchInstructions" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationType" type="ApplicationType">
        <TypeFieldValues>
            <TypeFieldValue value="Web application" type="WebApp" />
            <TypeFieldValue value="Remote machine" type="RemoteMachine" />
            <TypeFieldValue value="Client application" type="ClientApp" />
        </TypeFieldValues>
    </TypeField>
</TypeFields>
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please let me know which XML file needs updating.